# Какой сервер использует heroku для rails приложения?

Tags: heroku

Нужно ли что то менять в Gemfile что бы использовать на heroku отличный от webrick сервер?

Answer (score 3):

Насчет того, какой лучше посоветовать ничего не могу.
Вот что Heroku пишет по поводу выбора Puma в качестве сервера приложений: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server

Comment: ...и [чем предостерегает о Unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/594).